# Speed of "play tone" block

Tags: bbc-microbit

While playing around with the bbc microbit and the Microsoft Block Editor, I noticed a strange behavior with the "play tone" block. If I use the block in the web based editor, the speed is reasonable. But as soon as I send it to my device, it is way to fast.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Trivial testcase? Speed meaning duration or frequency?

Comment: duration. Testcase? Yeah, I could make a screenshot as soon as I am at my home pc again... It is just some "play tone" blocks in sequence...

Comment: Looks OK to me. If anything the simulator is a bit hit and miss (its OK with a single tone in a loop, but more and the timing does vary). 120 BPM, I measure 499ms for a single beat (using a DS1054)

Comment: thanx for the feedback. So I will give it another try.